# AJAX not working with onsubmit

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a test web page where I'm saving some text in the file on the server side. There is a script doing all the work by function saveFile(). Its working fine on the onclick event of a button, but when I set it to onsubmit event of a form, its going inside the script but not doing the ajax saving part.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function saveFile() {
          var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          var data = new FormData();
          data.append("data" , "teeeexxxxtttt");
          xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php",true);
          xmlhttp.send(data);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="saveFile()" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="test"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
<button type="button" onclick="saveFile()">Click Me!</button> 
</body>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $fname = mktime() . ".txt";
    $file = fopen($fname, 'w');
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I think you need to stop the default action of the form

Comment: do you get any error in console?

Comment: You should return something. `return true;`

Comment: What exactly is 'not working'?

Comment: Changing the default action of the form to my own didn't help.

Comment: @user3154108 ,As the question said, The onsubmit

Comment: @user3154108 Saving text to the file after submit.

Comment: you need to `return false` on the function

Comment: try taking the method post of the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this , calling the ajax function needs to get the return value as true or else it won't be called

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function saveFile() {
          var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          var data = new FormData();
          data.append("data" , "teeeexxxxtttt");
          xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php",true);
          xmlhttp.send(data);
          return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="return saveFile()" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="test"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
<button type="button" onclick="return saveFile()">Click Me!</button> 
</body>
```

Comment: You need to return **false**, not *true*. I fixed your code so it returns the correct Boolean.

Comment: @user1816806 change the true to `false` and make sure to add the `return` statement to the `onsubmit` attribute.

Comment: It worked, but after saving the file I would like to navigate to some page can it be achieved with the return false statement?

Comment: simply navigate in the ajax.php page

Comment: @epascarello I tested OP's code even without any returns, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- than you must have a buggy browser than does not do form submissions.

Comment: *"It worked, but after saving the file I would like to navigate to some page"* Seems weird that you would use Ajax if you want to navigate, but you would do it like @Walid did below. BUT you would use `window.location.href="newPage.html"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- The form will submit, the page will refresh, the Ajax call will not go out to the server unless it happens to beat the race condition. That is how it works.

Comment: @epascarello Sorry, my mistake. Browser issue; isn't it always? lol

Answer (score 0):

To prevent form to be really submitted before AJAX request has completed, the onsubmit event handler must return false. One way to do that:

```
<form id="form1" onsubmit="saveFile(); return false;">
```

To really submit the form when the AJAX request has completed:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
     document.getElementById("form1").submit();
   }
}
```